# Does QAbstractItemModel's sort notify the view?

Tags: qt5, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

I have implemented a custom `QAbstractItemModel` subclass, and from my understanding, the [`QAbstractItemModel::sort()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#sort) method can be overridden in a derived class to implement custom sorting logic, which I did.

However, I haven't included any code to emit a signal for view updates, because I'm not sure if it is necessary to do so within the `sort()` function.

Is the caller of the `sort()` function responsible for notifying the view, or should the `sort()` function handle this itself?

Comment: Take a look at [`QAbstractItemModel::layoutChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged), and [`QFileSystemModel::sort` source code](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qfilesystemmodel.cpp.html#_ZN16QFileSystemModel4sortEiN2Qt9SortOrderE) for an example.